# On what level can SPDY be used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, spdy

I'm curious how SPDY should be implemented when using an ASP.NET MVC application. As far as I know it is not the case by now, but should I wait for an updated MVC (5), new IIS-server, upgraded .net-framework, or something else?

Comment: `SPDY` is an application-level protocol. You would need a new IIS *and the clients would need a new browser* (IE does not yet support it).

Comment: Not entirely true, IE11 will support SPDY/3.

Comment: Confirming IE11 shows it loads facebook, google and others using SPDY protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of this question is "can I use spdy with my IIS based server and .net application".

As I understand it, IIS would need to implement the protocol, and/or a third party would need to offer a module for IIS that implements this. So far, I have not found either of these, but will update my answer if I do.

Comment: How about .net self hosting applications? Since there is no IIS, is there any support from .net framwork to facilitate HTTP/2? At least in the plan.